# Java set/setElementAt not setting the right value

Tags: java, algorithm, vector, combinatorics

I need to find all the permutations for a given n(user input) **without** backtracking.

What i tried is:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Vector;

class Main {

    private static int n;
    private static Vector<Vector<Integer>> permutations = new Vector<>();



    private static void get_n() {

        Scanner user = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("n = ");

        n = user.nextInt();
    }
    private static void display(Vector<Vector<Integer>> permutations) {

        for (int i = 0; i < factorial(n) - 1; ++i) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
                System.out.print(permutations.elementAt(i).elementAt(j) + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }



    private static int factorial(int n) {

        int result = 1;

        for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {

            result *= i;
        }

        return result;
    }
    private static int max(Vector<Integer> permutation) {

        int max = permutation.elementAt(0);

        for (int i = 1; i < permutation.size(); ++i)
            if (permutation.elementAt(i) > max)
                max = permutation.elementAt(i);

        return max;
    }



    //  CHECKS FOR ELEMENT COUNT AND 0 - (n-1) APPARITION
    public static int validate_permutation(Vector<Integer> permutation) {

        // GOOD NUMBER OF ELEMENTS
        if (max(permutation) != permutation.size() - 1)
            return 0;

        // PROPER ELEMENTS APPEAR
        for (int i = 0; i < permutation.size(); ++i)
            if (!permutation.contains(i))
                return 0;

        return 1;
    }

    private static Vector<Integer> next_permutation(Vector<Integer> permutation) {

        int i;

        do {
            i = 1;

            // INCREMENT LAST ELEMENT
            permutation.set(permutation.size() - i, permutation.elementAt(permutation.size() - i) + 1);

            // IN A P(n-1) PERMUTATION FOUND n. "OVERFLOW"
            while (permutation.elementAt(permutation.size() - i) == permutation.size()) {

                // RESET CURRENT POSITION
                permutation.set(permutation.size() - i, 0);

                // INCREMENT THE NEXT ONE
                ++i;
                permutation.set(permutation.size() - i, permutation.elementAt(permutation.size() - i) + 1);
            }
        } while (validate_permutation(permutation) == 0);


        // OUTPUT
        System.out.print("output of next_permutation:\t\t");
        for (int j = 0; j < permutation.size(); ++j)
            System.out.print(permutation.elementAt(j) + " ");
        System.out.println();

        return permutation;
    }

    private static Vector<Vector<Integer>> permutations_of(int n) {

        Vector<Vector<Integer>> permutations = new Vector<>();

        // INITIALIZE PERMUTATION SET WITH 0
        for (int i = 0; i < factorial(n); ++i) {

            permutations.addElement(new Vector<>());

            for(int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
                permutations.elementAt(i).addElement(0);
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            permutations.elementAt(0).set(i, i);

        for (int i = 1; i < factorial(n); ++i) {

            // ADD THE NEXT PERMUTATION TO THE SET
            permutations.setElementAt(next_permutation(permutations.elementAt(i - 1)), i);

            System.out.print("values set by permutations_of:\t");
            for (int j = 0; j < permutations.elementAt(i).size(); ++j)
                System.out.print(permutations.elementAt(i).elementAt(j)  + " ");
            System.out.println("\n");
        }

        System.out.print("\nFinal output of permutations_of:\n\n");
        display(permutations);

        return permutations;
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        get_n();

        permutations.addAll(permutations_of(n));
    }
}
```

Now, the problem is obvious when running the code. next_permutation outputs the correct permutations when called, the values are set correctly to the corresponding the vector of permutations, but the end result is a mass copy of the last permutation, which leads me to believe that every time a new permutation is outputted by next_permutation and set into the permutations vector, *somehow* that permutation is also copied over *all* of the other permutations. And I can't figure out why for the life of me.

I tried both set, setElementAt, and an implementation where I don't initialize the permutations vector fist, but add the permutations as they are outputted by next_permutation with add() and I hit the exact same problem. Is there some weird way in which Java handles memory? Or what would be the cause of this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
permutations.setElementAt(next_permutation(permutations.elementAt(i - 1)), i);
```

This is literally setting the vector at `permutations(i)` to be *the same object* as `permutations[i-1]`.  Not the same value - the exact same object.  I think this the source of your problems.  You instead need to copy the values in the vector.